# How to get reliable display of images on HTML page

Tags: html, image, python-2.7, flask

I am using Python 2.7, flask and HTML.

The app folder contains the Python program, static folder, and template folder.

Running the Python program renders the first HTML template which takes lot of inputs and a file upload. These inputs are processed by the Python program which then generates 7 matplotlib plots which are saved as PNG files in the static folder.

```
fig=plot.get_figure()

fig.savefig('static/PT.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The PNG files are all less than 50 kb

Finally the 2nd HTML page is rendered which should display these images from static folder.

```
<td align="center"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='PT.png') }}" alt="Image Placeholder" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"> </td>
```

Every time the program runs, the calculations changes, and the images are overwritten with new ones, but image names remain the same.

The problem is that sometimes all the images are displayed correctly, but sometimes not all of them are displayed. How can I get reliability in displaying of images?

Comment: can you try to delete the previous image before saving a new one?

Comment: Have you tried turning off caching on your browser when viewing the app? I'm not sure this is an issue w/ flask. The code looks fine.

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi  I have tried both options, but problem still persists